# How to add a space between every sequence of four characters (like a credit card number)?

Tags: php, split, spaces

How to split this string :

```
56A19E6D77828
```

into format like this :

```
56A1 9E6D 7782 8
```

Are there any native PHP functions built for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
$card = "56A19E6D77828";
echo join(" ", str_split($card, 4));
```

Outputs:

```
56A1 9E6D 7782 8
```

Answer (score 0):

For your sample input, this task can be completed **with one function call** and **without generating a temporary array**.

```
$string = '56A19E6D77828';
var_export(preg_replace('~.{4}\K~', ' ', $string));  // '56A1 9E6D 7782 8'
```

If you need to be careful to not add an extra trailing space when the string length is a factor of four, then just check that you haven't reached the end of string anchor.

```
$string = '56A19E6D77828333';
var_export(preg_replace('~.{4}\K(?!$)~', ' ', $string));  // '56A1 9E6D 7782 8333'
```

[Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/9Ka5u)

The pattern is simple:

1. match any four characters  (`.{4}`)
2. forget the match characters but retain the position (`\K`)
3. check that the end of the string hasn't been met (`(?!$)`
4. add the space to the position in the string

No string explosions or array implosions, just direct string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to split different numbers for each split and then join them together, It's super hacky but this works, had to split a gift card that gets rendered.

```
$card = "603628385592165882327";

$test = str_split($card, 6);
$test1 = str_split($card, 5);
$test2 = str_split($card, 6);
$test3 = str_split($card, 4);

$number = $test[0];
$number .= " ";
$number .=  $test1[1];
$number .= " ";
$number .=  $test2[2];
$number .= " ";
$number .=  $test3[3];

echo $number;
```

result

603628 83855 165882 1658